# Should OP be able to ask/answer a question anonymously?

Tags: feature-request, questions, answers, privacy

Stack Exchange is one of the best Q&A network I know. As a software developer, I am using it daily, asking question and contributing. As my Stack Overflow profile grows, it gets more and more interesting to provide in job applications. That's great.

Stack Exchange also has a lot of other great Communities next to Stack Overflow. Let's mention specifically the Health community, or also the Workplace community. OP might want to ask a critical or very private question. It might be even political. As OP hands in its Stack Overflow profile with a job application, its potential future employer can also get insight into OP's other profiles, as all is connected in the users Stack Exchange profile. (I guess you already see were I am going.) This can heavily influence the decision of a potential employer.

To avoid that, OP simply does not ask such question. This again means valuable content lost for Stack Exchange.

If OP could ask certain questions anonymously, Stack Overflow will have richer content and OP does not have to fear consequences.

To ask a question anonymously, **OP still needs to be logged in**, but other users won't see any user information. Also **OP would not gain any rep** from an anonymous question or answer. All other rules, down voting, locking account for bad actions and so on still apply.

Comment: There is nothing against creating a second, anonymous, account (as long as your two accounts **don't interact together**) to ask a question in such a situation.

Comment: Creating a second account to evade system restrictions (banning, throttling, etc) is also against the rules, I think. And creating multiple accounts (or an “anonymous account that doesn’t have to deal with consequences”) might run afoul of that.

Comment: Not sure about the "richer content" part.

Comment: Can't you hide certain communities you're a part of in your profile?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is Meta *Stack Overflow*. None of the reasons you've suggested for posting anonymously apply to this site.

Comment: I am voting this question **up** because it is a good question and new ideas are useful. I am also voting it to **leave open** because it deserves an answer.

Comment: I definitely agree that people should be able to ask anonymous questions (I don't see any reason for anonymous answers or comments, however), but I think I disagree with your reasoning as to why it's a good idea to allow them, if I understand your reasons, as they seem potentially a bit unethical (it's unclear whether or not they are, but I don't want to upvote something ambiguous). I'd like to upvote your feature request, but I don't want to upvote the reason for it without more information (so, I'm not voting). I do think the votes should go on the person's reputation unless it's CW, though.

Comment: @NicolBolas: If only MSO never got political.  Questions about the operation of MSO (and showing things on the main site sidebar -- which is often linked to MSO political activities) often come to MSO.

Comment: @BenVoigt: When I said "apply to this site," I meant "apply to Stack Overflow". I'm saying that he's talking about things that are only applicable to other SE sites. And since it's a feature request that is for them primarily, it is a feature request that should be discussed on Meta Stack Exchange, not here.

Comment: @NicolBolas: It's more applicable to other sites, but it is also applicable to SO and MSO.  Political postings show up on SO main site via the sidebar, and on MSO as questions.  And the diamond mods keep telling me that just because something is a concern network wide is not a reason to flag for migration, so...

Comment: @NicolBolas I did post it on the wrong site. Voting for close.

Comment: [How do I hide my accounts on a specific Stack Exchange site - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/290092/how-do-i-hide-my-accounts-on-a-specific-stack-exchange-site) (you can also make your username&image different on the hidden sites)

Answer (score 8):

I would argue that we should regard situations like this analogous to *every* employer that reads through social media and information online as extra context.

If you put it out there, it's safe for you to be judged on, but if they reject your employment because you asked a politically charged question somewhere on the Internet, you've dodged a bullet working for them.

Otherwise...I find it difficult to agree with your main point:

> If OP could ask certain questions anonymous, StackOverflow will have richer content and OP does not have to fear consequences.

Ever hear of the "G.I.F.T"?  I can't link you to it since I'm at work right now, but the basic premise is, if someone is anonymous online, it (more times than not) *empowers* them to act like complete jerks since the consequence of social ramification is reduced or eliminated.

Not just that, but I don't see how better questions could come from anonymous sources.  We have bad questions from pseudonymous sources as it is.

Lastly (and this *really* is just me being facetious at this point):

> To avoid that, OP simply does not ask such question. This again means valueable content lost for StackExchange.

Again, not sure I see this happening either.  The less questions asked on Stack Overflow, the more likely better answers are to rise to the surface, and the more likely better information is to be propagated.

Comment: *"... you've dodged a bullet working for them"* - Very good point.